# Random <li> on load, click & keydown

Tags: jquery, random

I'm not very good with jquery at all so I really apologise for my lack of knowledge but I'm trying to understand.

I have got this bit of code below which is pulling in a random `<li></li>` when the page loads. Which is great!

```
$(function(){
    $('#lome li').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    var min = 0;
    var max = $('#lome li').length;
    var randomLi = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    $('#lome li').eq(randomLi).show();
});
```

But I also want this to work with a .click function and a .keydown. How would I do this? I tried just trying that code above but using

```
$('.next').click(function()
```

This worked for the action of the click but on load of the page, it loaded all of the list items not jus ta random one.

Any advice is hugely appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why running the code under a click handler wouldn't work for you, but try this:

```
function showRandomLi() {
    var $li = $('#lome li').hide(); // note: no loop required here
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * $li.length);
    $li.eq(index).show();
}

$(function() {
    showRandomLi(); // on load
    $('.next')
        .click(showRandomLi)
        .keydown(function(e) {
            e.which == 39 && showRandomLi();
        });  
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzcnkmrf/)

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected token ; on this i'm afraid.

Comment: My bad, missed a closing bracket. Added a working example. Try now.

Comment: That worked fantastically, thank you. I don't mean to pest but also for .keydown? keycode 39?

Comment: Sorry that this is so late, but since you helped me so much last time. Whats the next step to make sure it doesnt show the randomLi two in a row or such?

Comment: @HeyImArt You're probably best to start a new question for that.